# Changes in the column values for machine learning

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression, supervised-learning

Below shown is the **engine** column that I have taken from a data set

| engine |
| --- |
| 2150 cc |
| 2240 cc |
| 2150 cc |
| 2230 cc |
| 2050 cc |
| 2280 cc |

I want my column **engine** to be like as shown below:

| engine |
| --- |
| 2150 |
| 2240 |
| 2150 |
| 2230 |
| 2050 |
| 2280 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the leading digits with a regex:

```
df['engine'] = df['engine'].str.extract('(^\d+)')
```

output:

```
  engine
0   2150
1   2240
2   2150
3   2230
4   2050
5   2280
```

If you need integers:

```
df['engine'] = df['engine'].str.extract('(^\d+)').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda to change the values of the column

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'engine' : ["2150 cc", "2240 cc", "2150 cc", "2230 cc", "2050 cc", "2280 cc"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['engine'] = df['engine'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(' c'))
```

Also you can replace non digit characters

```
df['engine'] = df['engine'].astype(str).str.replace('\D+', '', regex=True)
```